# How to close/open a view panel

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I can't find a way to close a view panel, in particular the horizontal at the bottom, is pretty useless to me at this moment.

[image]

Comment: Why would you ever want to close the logic editor? I overwrote the start up file to have that in it!

Comment: @X-27 that was almost two years ago when I started using blender, at that moment I was using it only as a 3d modelling tool

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That is the *Logic Editor* at the bottom, *(you probably opened it accidentally as it's not normally in the Default scene as you have it)*. In your case here, look in the corner of the panel where the little lines are.. *(these are called the viewport handles and are always in the upper top-right or lower bottom-left)*.

[image]

Left click the handle and drag **down**, an arrow will overlay the view as a sort of confirmation, just drag it down and it will 'close' that view.

Likewise, the process to open one is the same. You can also create new windows with these, Just <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on the handles in either corner and drag it to 'tear' it out that view into its own window. *(this just makes a copy of that view in its own window, the original stays the same)*

**NB:** A good point to further note is that to expand or collapse a view into another. They **must** be of the same width or height. Meaning, if the top has two views and the bottom has one wide one, you wouldn't be able to expand the bottom one.

Comment: Also if you happened to take the one in the very bottom left hand corner and drag _up_ it would give you a arrow to prompt and see if you wanted to close your 3d view (in this case) but if you don't want to close your 3d view, you can drag it back into the (in this case) game logic panel it would close the game logic panel instead

Comment: @gandalf3 actually no. Dragging up from the bottom left creates a duplicate of that view. I think you mean *upper right*?

Comment: @iKlsR I think he meant "upper right hand corner" of the *bottom window*.

Comment: I should update this answer so it's a bit more general.

Comment: In the above example, I've dragged the corner of the Properties pane up to make the Outliner pane go away but I don't see any trivial (single step) way to make the Properties pane go away so that I'm left with just the 3d View and (in my case) the Timeline pane below it. I was able to get what I want by dragging down the 3d View to make the Timeline pane go away and then dragging it right to make the Properties pane go away, then I added back the Timeline pane below it. (I have a 2nd monitor so the things I "got rid of" are on it.)

Comment: @lumpynose `Shift + Space` is a quick shortcut to get only the 3d view. If you get rid of the outliner the properties pane should now align with the 3d view so you should be able to join those.

Comment: This doesn't work, the handle cannot be dragged down. This answer is wrong or unclearly phrased.

Comment: What don't you understand about it or what's not working for you? Does another answer on this post have a better explanation? Share a picture / gif is possible @TomášZato

Comment: This must have been the first UI ever created and then no one else followed its conventions. Sorry, I'm just trying to account for its backasswardness.

Answer (score 67):

*An alternative to iKlsR's answer:*
You can close a panel by right clicking on the line between the two pannels (i.e. the shadowed area. Your mouse will turn into a double-sided arrow when you hover) and clicking join area:

[image: join/split area menu]

Comment: Also known as the pre-2.5 method. Which I use, cause I'm old and i never figured out the corners stuff. I set up screen sets and use them for ages anyway.