# Center View to cursor not working?

Tags: 3d-view

I am moving my cursor and going to View -> Align View -> Center View to Cursor. I have already had quite a few problems with blender such as not being able to select objects except in the list selector but this is just ridiculous. Is there any mode I could be in that would be stopping the view from centering itself?

Edit: It's because of that ridiculous second screen that I accidentally made appear by clicking somewhere near the top of the program. If I drag the toolbar down I can see that in my second view my character is centered on my cursor. How do I get rid of this view? I don't want it.

Comment: Did you Shift click the split region button? Or did you drag it?

Comment: Try this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel

Comment: @someonewithpc I dragged it up

Comment: Take a look at this:
 http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames and this: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames