# How to display a reference image in a new window?

Tags: interface, image

How do I open an extra window to display a reference image? How do I import the reference image into the window?

Comment: Please see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing

Comment: The questions is not a duplicate, it isn't asking how to add background images, it is asking how to make a **new window** to display the reference image.

Comment: read also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel

Answer (score 2):

## UV Image Editor

If you wan't to have it next to your 3d view, you can use the UV Image editor. To open a new one, click and drag to your right on the bottom left hand corner of the 3D view.

[image]

You will then see a second 3d view. click on the icon of a cube, and change it to the UV image editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but I am the newest of noobs, so I think I need to reframe my question. But I'll have to do it later. Perhaps you could check back in a few hours and bail me out!

Comment: @chas sure.... if it isn't exactly related, try asking a new question (if you're not sure then just ask it)

Comment: Okay... I looked again at the answers above, went back to blender, and after a few more tries succeeded in opening a new window and opening an image file in it. Thank you very much for your help! (I just hope I can do it again.)

Comment: @chas If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted, using the green check mark. If you need more help, feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 2):

## Background Image

You can use a background image in the same 3D view, by adding one in the properties panel on the right side of the view (you can toggle it with <kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Empty

You can also add a background image using an empty. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Empty*>*Image*. Go into the empty properties panel, and chose your image

[image]