# How to move my timeline window?

Tags: interface

My timeline has moved to the top window on my project somehow.  How do I move it to the bottom of the layout?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows? You need to join the viewport and the timeline and then split them again or drag the grip icon to create a new timeline window and then close the old one. See this exact answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5633/12