# I can't close render windows

Tags: rendering

I don't have much experience with Blender, as I only used it a few times. This time, I managed to do something I didn't want to while rendering something. Basically, I opened a few windows (picture below) and I have no idea how to close them. Pressing 'X' or any other button that's supposed to close them doesn't work. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel. In related question Logic editor window is discussed, in your case these are 3D View windows

Comment: @MrZak It works, and thanks on the quick response!