# How to close a window by hotkey instead of dragging?

Tags: interface

I know how to close windows by dragging, but that restricts me to only closing windows on the right-hand side of the screen, and sometimes windows get in positions where it is impossible to close them.

What is the hotkey/method to simply select a window and close it, without dragging?

Comment: It may be impossible to close Blender editors only if neighbor editor is split in 2 or more ones. It should be possible to close any window in the interface with method in [related question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel). If you aren't comfortable with dragging, you can `RMB` [click on the line splitting windows](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1225/1245) and select either `Split Area` or `Join Area` option.

Comment: A possible answer is: by change your workflow so that instead of dragging windows and window sizes you change "layouts". Create a layout for specific actions you that accommodate your needs, save them as part of your startup file. Then switching layouts is done with Ctrl+left or right arrow. See:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows