# Top Right Panel

Tags: interface

Ok real noob question here.But there used to be a panel over this one on the picture that showed all the objects in your blend.I think I might have hidden it some way.I want to know how to make it show again.

[image]

Comment: That one is called Outliner. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Drag the corner to create a new window

2 - Select in the dropdown menu the outliner

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Blender panels and viewports are highly customizable, Check the top left Icon in this panel and choose "Outliner"to get that panel back.