# How do i close a view window that's not the same size as the ones next to it?

Tags: interface, windows

I'd like to close one of the view windows on the right side of the Blender user interface. However, it shares borders with two view windows on its left. I've tried dragging both its and its neighbor's viewport handles. I've tried clicking on the boundary and selecting "Join Area" under the Area Options menu. Neither of those work. I checked [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel), [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows), and others, but those don't help because the view window I want to close shares borders with more than one other view window. I'm using version 2.74. How can I close theview window?

[image]

Comment: Just to preempt... This might look like a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows but I think this is a special case that isn't obviously answered by the other.

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel

Comment: @Matt Thanks! I edited the question to clarify why this is different than those other questions.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! I edited the question to clarify why this is different than those other questions.

Comment: From @iKisR [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel): "NB: A good point to further note is that to expand or collapse a view into another. They must be of the same width or height. Meaning, if the top has two views and the bottom has one wide one, you wouldn't be able to expand the bottom one."

Comment: While it's true that the information is there, I actually prefer this question because it's more clear about being an edge-case. If someone is having this problem, I think this question will show up in search results more easily than the other will.

Comment: @Matt I didn't mean to close this one as duplicate; however the information was included there (btw in your answer too). Related posts lack guides / notes about this behaviour though, so this one can be used as more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.

The most direct option is to expend the 3D Viewport over the timline, so that the 3D Viewport is the same size as the Outliner. Then expand the 3D Viewport over the Outliner. Then split the 3D Viewport, and make the timeline again.

The other option is to split the Outliner horizontally. Then line that border up with the border between the 3D Viewport and the Timeline, then expand the 3D Viewport over the top Outliner pane, and expand the Timeline over the bottom Outliner pane.

For more detail on how to expand these panes, check out [How to close view windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows)

ALTERNATIVELY, if you're wanting to make the 3D Viewport bigger, just hover your mouse over it and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>. Then <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> again to return it to its original size. This lets you maximize your 3D Viewport space without losing the all-important Properties panel. I'd highly recommend changing that Outliner into a Properties panel... you'll be using it ALL the time, and then use the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> trick to alternate between full-screen and regular layout. In fact, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> will work with any pane all the time.