# Closing Extra Windows

Tags: interface

I've been having a problem in the software recently, and it's been bothering me a lot.  I accidentally either opened this console or expanded it from the top, *(currently empty as I just reopened the file, didn't help, )* and it wont close or shrink.  ***(see picture below)***  I've looked at other guides similar to this, and nothing's helped.  The main problem I've had is that any time I try to merge it, it just creates a new ribbon with file, render, etc., and no guides cover this topic.  I don't know what to do, and can't find any guides, so I hope you can help!

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Tutorial for everyone ..... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlj_4nlJWpo

Comment: Two windows A and B can only be merged if they share one border [entirely] and they were created with by splitting.  Otherwise NO. Try to merge only windows that have this property. If you try to do otherwise you will simply create a new window.  Your question is natural and a general knowledge of the Blender UI will help you more than just this question. So a tutorial video will help. I have experienced no way to close a window simply because it occupies an entire application edge. Maybe I should see the tutorial.

Comment: Knowledge of switching window layouts and maximizing a window may lessen your concern above.  See the aforementioned tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close view windows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-to-close-view-windows) and [How can I reset my menus?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus/8394#8394)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/how-do-i-close-a-view-window-thats-not-the-same-size-as-the-ones-next-to-it

Comment: Also instead of making a mess of the interface, it is more productive to create layouts that facilitate your particular style of working. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep the [Info Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/introduction.html) at the top of your window.

You can resize it so that only the header is visible as most times that is all you will use.

- Start by opening a new file.
- move the cursor to the bottom of the info header until you get a double arrowed cursor, then drag up until only the header is visible.

[image: example resizing editor]

- Select [*File->Save Startup File*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/startup_file.html). This is why you want to start with a new file, saving the startup file will keep this screen layout every time you start blender.

Note that any files you saved with the altered screen layout can be opened with that layout, disable the *Load UI* option to use your saved default layout. you can change the default [Load UI option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/file.html#save-load) in your preferences.

[image: Load UI option]