# Lost UI properties bar and can't get rid of other bars

Tags: edit-mode

This properties bar:

[image]

disappeared when I accidentally opened the Grease pencil bar. Now the area where the properties bar looks like this:

[image]

I cannot collapse it, and I cannot get the properties toolbar back!
How would I do it?

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/how-to-close-open-a-view-panel. Looks like you opened UV editor window instead of the Outliner, inside that UV editor open up the menu with editors and find Outliner there or press Shift+F9.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its something like this
[image]

Please save your file, close blender and re open it, open your blender file and un check the **Load UI** check box as shown below:

[image]

We are all set:

[image]

Best of luck!